# SQL - Update when source column is not blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm facing some trouble when doing an update

Now I'm trying to do update with condition below:

1. If the **source table has null value** or **empty string** and **target has value**, it will **not update**
2. If the **source table has value** and **target value is null or empty string** it will **update**
3. If **both has value** then it will **update the target value from source value**

I have tried using `OR` in `WHERE` clause but it still update when the source is empty string
Here is my code

```
UPDATE a
SET a.column1 = b.column1
    a.column2 = b.column2
    a.column3 = b.column3
    .....
from TARGET t
inner join SOURCE s
on t.name = s.name
and t.gender = s.gender
where (
    s.column1 <> ''
    s.column2 <> ''
    s.column3 <> ''
    ........
)
```

I have an idea to use `CASE WHEN` on every column but I think that's my last option.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually you probably need both, a where clause that covers all update conditions, and a case expression per column to ensure each column only updates when required. However to clarify you question please provide some sample data that illustrates at least all of conditions you describe. And then your desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Condition 1 : use `NULLIF()` to check for empty string and then `COALESCE()` to check for column1, if it is null, set it back to `t.column1`.

```
UPDATE t
SET   column1 = COALESCE(NULLIF(s.column1, ''), t.column1)
```

Condition 2 : check in `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE s.column1 IS NOT NULL 
AND   s.column1 <> ''
```

Condition 3 is actually already handled by 1 & 2.

And to handle checking multiple columns, use `OR` on the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE (s.column1 IS NOT NULL AND   s.column1 <> '')
OR    (s.column2 IS NOT NULL AND   s.column2 <> '')
OR    (s.column3 IS NOT NULL AND   s.column3 <> '')
```

Answer (score 0):

As on column may be empty when another contains a value and can be updated you can use a CASE statement like.
If you only want to update if all values a empty or null you need to put all the conditions in the where.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.column1 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(a.column1, '') = '' THEN b.column1 ELSE a.column1 END
    a.column2 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(a.column2, '') = '' THEN b.column2 ELSE a.column2 END
    a.column3 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(a.column3, '') = '' THEN b.column3 ELSE a.column3 END
from TARGET t
inner join SOURCE s
on t.name = s.name
and t.gender = s.gender;
```

with all WHERE conditions

```
UPDATE a
SET a.column1 = b.column1
    a.column2 = b.column2
    a.column3 = b.column3
    .....
from TARGET t
inner join SOURCE s
on t.name = s.name
and t.gender = s.gender
where (
    (a.column1 = '' OR a.culumn1 IS NULL)
AND (a.column2 = '' OR a.culumn2 IS NULL)
AND (a.column3 = '' OR a.culumn3 IS NULL)
AND b.column1 IS NOT NULL
AND b.column2 IS NOT NULL
AND b.column3 IS NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. And it seems a check to see whether a row should be updated would be helpful, updating an entire table is not usually a good idea.